# Is the message attribute of an exception in try catch ever an empty string or NULL?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I cannot find a definitive answer, and well the MS docs are not the greatest so here goes to finding an answer versus being cast into down vote hell.

Consider this simple code:

```
    try
    {
        if (errMessage.Contains(EXCEPTIONCOMPARISONMESSAGE))
        {
            //do stuff;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("isAbleConvertToPDF: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
```

My question is will `ex.Message` ever be an empty string or NULL?  I *think* NOT, but I cannot find a definitive documented answer.

Looking for documentation to back up the answer given too please.

Comment: Sure: `throw new Exception("");`

Comment: What would you do differently if it were?

Comment: @DStanley Of course I will account for it, but that isn't what I was asking....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible - a custom exception (one that inherits from `Exception`) could return a null or empty string.

The `Exception` constructor also takes a message as a parameter, which could be an empty string.

There is nothing in the interface contract to indicate that the message can never be empty or null, so you should assume that it *could* be empty or null.

Here's an example, filling in your example code:

```
try
{
    if (errMessage.Contains(EXCEPTIONCOMPARISONMESSAGE))
    {
        throw new MyEvilException();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                                                V--------V this will be null
    eventLog.WriteEntry("isAbleConvertToPDF: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
}

private class MyEvilException : Exception
{
    public override String Message 
    {
        get 
        {  
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Exception` is base class for other exceptions where `Message` property is marked as `virtual`.
Which mean that `Message` can be empty string or `null`, because every derived class can override it.

However actual implementation of `Message` in `Exception` class looks like

```
public virtual String Message 
{
    get 
    {  
        if (_message == null) 
        {
            if (_className==null) 
            {
                _className = GetClassName();
            }
            return Environment.GetResourceString("Exception_WasThrown", _className);

        } 
        else 
        {
            return _message;
        }
    }
}
```

So you can see from above, that `null` will never be returned from `Exception` base class, but empty string will be returned when `throw new Exception(string.Empty);`

Comment: virtual...that is what I was missing.

Comment: `null` could be returned if a derived class overrides the property getter.

Comment: @DStanley, as I said on the top of answer. Bottom sentence is about base class `Exception`